# TypeError message with web2py and numpy

Tags: python, numpy, web2py

Little perplexed here. I have some code that runs fine directly:

```
results = INPUT
dates = set(results[0])
sectors = set(results[2])
columns = ["Port Wt", "Bench Wt", "Port Retn", "Bench Retn", "Attrib", "Select", "Inter", "Total"]
results.fillna(0,inplace=True)

sectors = sorted(sectors)
test = np.ones([len(sectors) + 1, len(columns)])
for date in dates:
    day = results[results[0] == date]
    for n, sector in enumerate(sectors):
        s = day[day[2] == unicode(sector)]
        pw = s.iloc[:,4].sum()
        bw = s.iloc[:,6].sum()
        pr = s.apply(lambda x: x.ix[5]/100 * x.ix[4], axis=1).sum().sum()
        br = s.apply(lambda x: x.ix[5]/100 * x.ix[6], axis=1).sum().sum()
        test[n,:] *= [(1. + pw)**(1./len(dates)), (1.+bw) ** (1./len(dates)), 1. + pr , 1. + br , 1. ,
                      1. , 1. , 1.]
test -= 1.
```

but when I run it in a web2py controller

```
def test():
    portfolio = "usequity"
    benchmark = "SP500"
    startdate = "2013-01-11 00:00:00"
    enddate = "2013-01-30 00:00:00"
    level1 = 'sector'
    level2 = 'industry'
    i1 = datadrawn.results(portfolio,benchmark,startdate,enddate,level1,level2,cr)
    i2 = datadrawn.sectors(i1['portfolio'], i1['benchmark'])
    i3 = datadrawn.brinson(i2)
    return dict(i3=i3)
```

I get the error

```
<type 'exceptions.TypeError'>(unsupported operand type(s) for *=: 'numpy.ndarray' and 'list')
```

local variables look okay to me..

```
locals request session response
locals
INPUT   :    0 4 ... ... ... ... [6422 rows x 7 columns]
br      :    0.0002428845794774927
bw      :    0.12515205797541681
columns :   ['Port Wt', 'Bench Wt', 'Port Retn', 'Bench Retn', 'Attrib', 'Select', 'Inter', 'Total']
date    :    u'2013-01-11 00:00:00'
dates   :    set([u'2013-01-11 00:00:00', u'2013-01-14 00:00:00', u'2013-01-15 00:00:00', u'2013-01-16 00:00:00', u'2013-01-17 00:00:00', u'2013-01-18 00:00:00', ...])
day     :    0 4 ..... ... ... [494 rows x 7 columns]
n       :    0
pr      :   -9.970633274708913e-05
pw      :    0.075036537596357311
results :    0 4 ... ... ... ... [6422 rows x 7 columns]
s       :    0 4 ...... ... ... [82 rows x 7 columns]
sector  :    u'Consumer Discretionary'
sectors :   [u'Consumer Discretionary', u'Consumer Staples', u'Energy', u'Financials', u'Health Care', u'Industrials', u'Information Technology', u'Materials', u'Telecommunications Services', u'Utilities']
test    :    array([[1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0],...0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0, 1.0]], dtype=float64)
```

Some research suggested that this may be array mistyping, but I've converted everything back to float as far as I can tell.

Any help greatly appreciated.

Comment: From what you have shared, it is not clear you are really running the same code inside and outside of web2py (i.e., how is the web2py code calling that first code block?). Also, in the first block of code, it does look like you've got an ndarray to the left of the `*=` and a list to the right -- if `*=` doesn't support those two types, then this should fail.

Comment: Hi @Anthony, apologies for the excess of brevity. web2py is calling the first block as a module import. it is one of the methods in a module named `datadrawn`. This definitely works when run within the module directly so I'm fairly confident the numpy aspects work...

Comment: To be clear, the first code block is part of the definition of the `datadrawn.results` method? In that case, the first step is to confirm that web2py is calling the method with the exact same arguments (and argument types) as when you run the method externally. Regarding the error, are you saying that the TypeError is somehow mistaken and that `*=` should in fact support an ndarray and a list, or are you saying that the code does not in fact include an ndarray and a list?

Comment: Hi @Anthony. Yes the first code block is part of datadrawn.results. I've just tried multiplying `np.array([1,2,3,4], dtype ='d') *= [1,2,3,1]` and it worked so I guess the TypeError doesnt make sense

Comment: Seems like a numpy issue. You should try calling the `datadrawn.results` method with the exact arguments from web2py to see if you get the same error (looks like all the arguments are just fixed strings, except `cr`, which doesn't appear in the code you've shown).

Comment: Hi @Anthony. `cr` is the cursor which I'm passing alongside. The exact same data `copy-pasted`. I've completely re-written the code using pandas to see if it was a direct or outdated numpy issue but still getting the `numpy-inside` issue described above.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/66167/discussion-between-tahnoon-pasha-and-anthony).